# Why do we use derating factors when sizing conductors?

Tags: electric-machine, electrically-conductive

What is the main reason behind using derating factors in case of determining the cross sectional area of a conductor and what happens if we don't take these factors into account ?

Comment: Please quote an example.

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to the american National Electrical Code?

Comment: "cable" = conductor? "cable sizing" = cable length or cable diameter? SWUMnMWUS

Comment: the cross sectional area

Comment: Maybe using safety factors for engineering specifications in almost any circumstance?

Comment: There's three kinds of limits that come to mind: corona for HV wires, electromigration for IC internal wiring, and fire safety in building wiring.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is that it provides a safe operational limit for specific conductors based upon insulation type, installation method, and temperature (among other conditions).  The National Electrical Code (NEC) gives specific guidance in article 310.  The manufacturer's product data gives a value based on material construction without regard to application.  De-rating is necessary to ensure that no damage occurs to the conductor or insulation.  For example, multiple conductors installed within the same conduit or raceway would typically be rated at a lower ampacity compared to a single conductor of the same cross sectional area installed in free-air.

Answer (score 2):

The true answer: To prevent fires.

The simple answer: To keep the temperature of the wire insulation below breakdown temperature.

The boring answer (with example):

Copper melts at 1085°C, but wire insulation goes through irreversible changes at  temperatures less than 100°C, depending on wire type. For example, XLPE insulation: XHHW 75°C (Linked reference).

Any wire has a small resistance \$R_{Feeder} \$.  As current flows through it, there will be a power loss to the wire.  This power loss is in the form of heat (\$P_{Feeder} = I_{Load}^2R_{Feeder} \$).  The temperature of the wire increases.

#10 copper (XHHW) can have an ampacity (maximum current) of 35A, but electricians derate it by 80% for safety (28A).  This current must also be derated for:

- proximity to other current carrying conductors.
- the cable sheath or raceway material.
- ambient temperatures > 30°C.

All of these conditions cause the temperature of the wire environment to be hotter.  If either or all of these conditions occur, then the ampacity (maximum current) must be derated to compensate for the increased thermal environment.

Typically, there are no raceways or sheath materials (coating to protect wire insulation) in homes.  The NEC Table attached has no derating factor for sheath materials because a wire in a home or a business will not be exposed to different environmental conditions.  But on a steel ship for example, power cables are run in raceways and cable sheaths are used for HOFR (Heat & Oil Resistant & Flame Retardant) protection.  XLPE breaks down if exposed to oils or greases.

So a #10 copper XHHW three-phase AC cable operating in a raceway with four other three-phase AC cables with three (total) operating simultaneously and an ambient temperature of 35°C.

- Safety = 80%.
- 3 * 3 = 9 total conductors carrying current at the same time = 70%.
- ambient temperature of 35°C = 94%.

$$ 35A \times (80\% \times 70\% \times 94\%) = 18.4A $$

If you want an operating current above that, you have to go to a larger wire size.  Ignore it and fire, death and destruction are possible (waxes poetically), if normally operating current is above 18.4A.

[National Electrical Code](http://www.usawire-cable.com/pdfs/nec%20ampacities.pdf)

Comment: Are there any differences between standards, I'm working with european standard NF C 15-100 and it's a bit different from NEC. Are there going to be different cable cross sectional area if i used 2 standards formthe same base current

Comment: I'm far from an expert and more familiar with the marine standards.  Each standard is unique based upon issuing body and level of safety, but there are more similarities, than true differences.  After all we are dealing the same physics and chemistry.